# Muxless Graphics and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, radeon, hybrid-graphics, amd-graphics

I have a laptop with muxless graphics (Intel HD 4000 and AMD radeon HD 7730m), and today I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
 The installation went fine, I was able to boot my computer and I updated the software using the software updater. The next time I was trying to boot, it just stuck on purple screen. I tried booting up again and then I saw the recovering journal screen, and afterwards many radeon errors. I saw clearly this one:
[Radeon]: failed testing ib on ring 7 .

Every time I boot my computer once, it stucks at purple screen, but if I boot it again it shows some radeon errors and boot up normally.

That's very annoying to boot up the computer twice, so I searched for a solution.
Fglrx is not an option since it does not support ubuntu 16.04.
Tried nomodeset, nolapic, noapic, acpi=off. All with no success. Even disabling quiet splash shows nothing than a purple screen. Tried to access tty with no success and tried booting with upstart (thought it will change something...)

I wanted to ask if muxless switchable cards are even supported by Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and how can I fix my problem? I couldn't find an answer anywhere, and if it is not supported, then how it is LTS release if it doesn't even support many graphic cards.

Comment: It seems like a complicating problem, so using http://paste.ubuntu.com/ provide us one link with the contents of the `~/.xsession-errors` file and a second link with the contents of `~/.xsession-errors.old` file. Provide also a third link for `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and a fourth for `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`. Also provide a 5th link with the output of `inxi -SMCGxxx` for more system info.